# Use companion computer as pass through for mission planner

Tags: dronekit-python, dronekit

I need to connect Mission Planner to a companion computer which is then connected to an APM. However, as far as I can tell, DKPY2 does not output like Mavproxy used to. I know that the Pixhawk can take multiple inputs from Mavlink commands, but I'd rather not have to upgrade right now. Is there a workaround besides adding my own implementation to DKPY2?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use MAVProxy.  You can add the following line to a startup script on your companion computer:

`mavproxy.py --master=/dev/ttyUSB0 --out=0.0.0.0:14550`

Replace the IP address with the IP of the computer running MP.

Comment: Are you suggesting that I route both the DKPY2 and MP commands through a separate mavproxy instance?